# jquery remove() not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery

```js
$('ul#a li')
  .click(function() {
    alert('List Item Clicked')
  })
  .parent()
  .clone(true)
  .find('li')
  .appendTo('#b')
  .end()
  .end()
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="a">
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul id="b"></ul>
```

I thought `.remove()` would remove `ul#a` but it is not removed as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more call to `.end()`. You're removing the clone of `ul#a`, not the original.

I guess `appendTo()` is pushing onto the jQuery object stack, so you need to end that.

```js
$('ul#a li')
  .click(function() {
    alert('List Item Clicked')
  })
  .parent()
  .clone(true)
  .find('li')
  .appendTo('#b')
  .end()
  .end()
  .end()
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="a">
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul id="b"></ul>
```

Comment: how about this? https://codepen.io/logan-lee/pen/VwwrVxG how does this work?

Comment: It's removing all the `li` that were appended to `#b`.

Comment: So `#a` still has its original contents, and `#b` is empty.

Comment: what does end() do here?

Comment: When a jQuery function returns a collection of elements, it pushes the collection that it was called on onto a stack. `.end()` pops the stack. `parent()`, `clone()`, `find()`, `appendTo()` each return new collections, `.end()` backs up one call so you can operate on that collection.

Comment: what would be returned by appendTo()? I know what it does but what collection is returned?

Comment: the codepen example: appendTo() is canceled by end() then clone is removed by remove(). does that seem right? but if i omit remove() both list are shown.

Comment: `.appendTo()` returns the elements that you're appending; contrast with `.append()`, which returns the element you're appending to. Read the documentation, it explains what every function returns.